# How do I troubleshoot animator issues in Unity WebGL builds?

Tags: unity-game-engine, webgl

I recently made a small change to my animator and in webgl it no longer triggers any of my animations aside from the one set to default.

I tried looking at the source but there's no errors in the console and I'm really not sure which file has the animator code in it in webgl.

Comment: Are these changes also working in Editor / Standalone builds? Or is it just WebGL failing? Without seeing the Animator it is hard to say what the issue could be. As for debugging the issue, I would first see if it is replicated elsewhere and if it is not, you will need to create your own debugger. Create a console UI window and display various information that can help see the internals of the animations.

Comment: After looking into it for a bit, another solution could be to disable `Code stripping` in player settings. Apparently, there was a bug with StateMachines in WebGL. I am unsure which Unity version you are in, but this could fix the issue.

Comment: I gave disabling code stripping a try but it didn't seem to resolve the issue. The only change I made to the animator was to add a new int to it and make some transitions based on it.

They work on the editor, I haven't tried standalone builds though,  I will give that a try!

Comment: The issue is present in the standalone build, I will see about hooking the debugger up to the build somehow.